# TypeError: pushDefaultLayers() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I am typing this command '`WAT_CONF=config.conf python watbridge.py`' while creating wat-bridge but getting the error like

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "watbridge.py", line 40, in <module>
    from wat_bridge.listeners import tg_listener, wa_listener
  File "/home/arpit_goyall/wat-bridge/wat_bridge/listeners.py", line 34, in <module>
    from wat_bridge.wa import WA_STACK, _connect_signal
  File "/home/arpit_goyall/wat-bridge/wat_bridge/wa.py", line 127, in <module>
    .pushDefaultLayers(True)
TypeError: pushDefaultLayers() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: The error message tells that .pushdefaultLayers does not take argument, only self is good. It may be provoked by a different version of the yowsup lib

Comment: Someone opened a PR to fix the problem https://github.com/rmed/wat-bridge/pull/10/commits/64969c5be8ecbe47483edea7ed85476d3df8c49d

Comment: I changed it but the same error is coming I think it is because of the new yowsup update that is it not send password anymore so basically I want to know that what is the new process of bridging Whatsapp and telegram can you help me!